# Adding buttons programatically not positioned properly

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to add buttons programatically to a view, but they seem to be unexpectedly positioned. Can anyone tell what is wrong:

```
    for var i = 0; i < 10; i++ {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        let x1 = i * 20
        let x2 = i * 20 + 15
        button.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(x1), 20, CGFloat(x2), 40)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center

        button.setTitle(String(i + 1), forState: .Normal)

        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
```

And the result:
[image]

Comment: `x2` is the button's width, but you seem to calculate maxX.

Comment: Each button is wider than it's predecessor. The buttons seem to be shiftet one on another and so you cant see the textlabel of most buttons. Button 9 (10) is 195 points wide.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. I though x2 is a position and not button width. Any reason the button text is in white BTW?

Comment: [Refer to the documentation for the title color](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitleColor:forState:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third argument in CGRectMake is width, not x2. So you should pass 15 (or what your desired width of button is). Also consider using swift version of CGRect initializer - CGRect(x: y: width: height: ) - as it uses named parameters